# How to print values in a dictionary that fall below a certain percentage?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I need a code to print out the names of any student who has one or more quiz scores under 70, followed by a sorted list of that student's quiz scores that are under 70.

ie.

```
quiz_scores = {
    'Corbin': [92, 66, 88, 91, 100, 95, 94],
    'Kevin': [100, 99, 100, 98, 95, 98, 99],
    'Hannah': [79, 67, 78, 81, 70, 55, 74],
    'Ben': [94, 88, 85, 100, 91, 79, 88],
    'Yasaswini': [99, 90, 88, 91, 89, 95, 94],
    'Veda': [79, 97, 88, 82, 70, 95, 94],
    'Jack': [59, 67, 74, 91, 70, 75, 56]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the working code

```
quiz_scores = {
    'Corbin': [92, 66, 88, 91, 100, 95, 94],
    'Kevin': [100, 99, 100, 98, 95, 98, 99],
    'Hannah': [79, 67, 78, 81, 70, 55, 74],
    'Ben': [94, 88, 85, 100, 91, 79, 88],
    'Yasaswini': [99, 90, 88, 91, 89, 95, 94],
    'Veda': [79, 97, 88, 82, 70, 95, 94],
    'Jack': [59, 67, 74, 91, 70, 75, 56]
}

print({name: [score for score in scores if score < 70] for name, scores in quiz_scores.items() if min(*scores) < 70})
```

And sample output

```
> python run.py
{'Corbin': [66], 'Hannah': [67, 55], 'Jack': [59, 67, 56]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame(quiz_scores).T.unstack()
a = pd.DataFrame(df[df < 70])
a = a[0].sort_values() 
a.reset_index().groupby('level_1')[0].apply(list).to_dict()                                                                                                                                       
# {'Corbin': [66], 'Hannah': [55, 67], 'Jack': [56, 59, 67]}
```